# Python opening large fits data buffer size error

Tags: python, size, astropy, fits

I tried to open a big IDL-generated fits data cube (159,2,4096,4096):

```
In [37]: hdulist = fits.open('/randpath/randname1.fits')

In [38]: hdulist.info()
Filename: /randpath/randname1.fits
No.    Name         Type      Cards   Dimensions   Format
0    PRIMARY     PrimaryHDU      11   (159, 2, 4096, 4096)   float32   

In [39]: scidata = hdulist[0].data
```

The following error occurred:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-d492d4e07eb1> in <module>()
----> 1 scidata = hdulist[0].data

/opt/local/anaconda/anaconda-2.2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astropy/utils/decorators.py in __get__(self, obj, owner)
    513             return obj.__dict__[self._key]
    514         except KeyError:
--> 515             val = self.fget(obj)
    516             obj.__dict__[self._key] = val
    517             return val

/opt/local/anaconda/anaconda-2.2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/hdu/image.py in data(self)
    206             return
    207 
--> 208         data = self._get_scaled_image_data(self._data_offset, self.shape)
    209         self._update_header_scale_info(data.dtype)
    210 

/opt/local/anaconda/anaconda-2.2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/hdu/image.py in _get_scaled_image_data(self, offset, shape)
    619         code = BITPIX2DTYPE[self._orig_bitpix]
    620 
--> 621         raw_data = self._get_raw_data(shape, code, offset)
    622         raw_data.dtype = raw_data.dtype.newbyteorder('>')
    623 

/opt/local/anaconda/anaconda-2.2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/hdu/base.py in _get_raw_data(self, shape, code, offset)
    566                               offset=offset)
    567         elif self._file:
--> 568             return self._file.readarray(offset=offset, dtype=code, shape=shape)
    569         else:
    570             return None

/opt/local/anaconda/anaconda-2.2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/file.py in readarray(self, size, offset, dtype, shape)
    272 
    273             return np.ndarray(shape=shape, dtype=dtype, offset=offset,
--> 274                               buffer=self._mmap)
    275         else:
    276             count = reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, shape)

TypeError: buffer is too small for requested array
```

The averaged array (2,4096,4096) works well:

```
In [40]: hdulist2 = fits.open('/randpath/randname1avg.fits')

In [41]: hdulist2.info()
Filename: /randpath/randname1avg.fits
No.    Name         Type      Cards   Dimensions   Format
0    PRIMARY     PrimaryHDU      10   (2, 4096, 4096)   float32   

In [42]: scidata2 = hdulist2[0].data
```

Any ideas? It seems that size matters for some reason. MATLAB cannot open the first fits file either:

```
Warning: Seek failed, 'Offset is bad - after end-of-file or last character written.'.   File may be an
invalid FITS file or corrupt.  Output structure may not contain complete file information. 
> In fitsinfo>skipHduData (line 721)
  In fitsinfo (line 226)
  In fitsread (line 99) 
Error using fitsiolib
CFITSIO library error (108): error reading from FITS file

Error in matlab.io.fits.readImg (line 85)
imgdata = fitsiolib('read_subset',fptr,fpixel,lpixel,inc);

Error in fitsread>read_image_hdu (line 438)
    data = fits.readImg(fptr);

Error in fitsread (line 125)
        data = read_image_hdu(info,1,raw,pixelRegion);
```

IDL can, for unclear reasons. Is there a limit to the array size when running the astropy.io workflow? Random matrices of the same size can be generated without problems. I'm currently working on a machine with 256 GB RAM, so memory should not play at role, should it? Thanks for all the help!

Update: The first time the hdulist is loaded Python actually gives some more useful error message:

WARNING: File may have been truncated: actual file length (4160755136) is smaller than the expected size (21340624320) [astropy.io.fits.file]
Indeed the file size is only 3.9 GB contrary to the expected ~ 20 GB. I'll have to double-check (don't have much experience with IDL) but for some reason it (writefits) cannot create the fits file properly.

Update 2: Problem solved. IDL 6.2 (an old version installed on the machine) apparently cannot deal with too large files, IDL 8.3 (which is also installed) can. No idea why, though.

Comment: A quick search for the main error message "TypeError: buffer is too small for requested array" suggests this error may pop up when a file is corrupt; not per se when it's too large (despite the, in those cases misleading, error message). MATLAB seems to think so as well: the FITS file is corrupt. See if you can open it in another FITS reader (e.g., `fv` if you have it), or try and use the [`fitsverify`](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/software/ftools/fitsverify/) tool. But it actually sounds like IDL messed up when writing the file to disk. Perhaps try another format, e.g. HDF5?

Comment: "the file size is only 3.9 GB contrary to the expected ~ 20 GB": that just shouts 32 bit (pointer size) limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to IDL 6.2 and does not appear anymore in IDL 8.3. It can thus be avoided by using current IDL versions for generating the fits file.

Comment: It look like the file is corrupt in some way, so as you found using the updated IDL I guess it fixed whatever bug caused the corrupt output (that said it's too bad Astropy didn't detect this cleanly and give a better error--it would help if you opened an issue on Astropy's github and provided a link to an example file that exhibits the problem).